# hover sticking on disabled inputs in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to add hovering on divs that contain checkboxes and will add a highlighting effect.  The issue i am having is that the hovering seems to stick when the inputs are disabled.  I have increased the width of each input to make the click area bigger and that seems to be causing an issue and would prefer not to change the width.  I cannot simply change this to a table because this is a much simpler version of the real thing...

I am not sure if this selector is all i need or if there is some sort of easy change i can make with the selector or change my html.  This only seems to be an issue in Chrome.

```
$('.checkboxes div').hover(function() {
```

Here is my fiddle.  It's kind of hard to reproduce but I get it to happen easier on the bottom row. You don't have to click it, just have to hover to make it happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/agroth3/2CTd8/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would be better off using a table, with a CSS style `tr:hover td:first-child{blah}`

Comment: ya i know, but i am stuck doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do a check with http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/ something like this could easily work for you `$('.checkboxes:enabled div').hover(function() {`

Comment: i need to it to work on all checkboxes, both disabled and enabled.  I am trying to mimic row highlighting that a table has, but i need to keep the structure i have, did you look at the fiddle??

Comment: if thats the case then just remove the `:enabled` and that should work you can change it to this if that doesnt work `$('input[type=checkbox]').hover(function() {`